# Professor Xavier's suit trousers in X2: X-Men United

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-2

I was watching X2:X-Men United and caught the scene when Xavier visits Magneto in the plastic prison. They scanned Xavier for metal and found none.

My question is regarding Professor X's suit trousers. Presumably, these would be normal and have a metal zipper so did the prison provide him with sweatpants or another type of trousers *without a zipper*, or did Xavier think of that at home and wear pants without a zipper from his home?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the movie we see Professor X wearing three suits. On the day in question, he wears a dark blue suit **with matching trousers**.

Under the circumstances, we can presume from the fact that he also supplied his own non-metallic wheelchair (knowing that he'll need to pass through a metal detector) that the Professor personally owns at least one pair of suit trousers, either with a **[nylon zipper](http://www.paskalusa.com/MouldedZippers.html)** or **plastic buttons** (hat tip to @benBolker for pointing out the obvious).

It would be highly unlikely that the prison would supply clothing to him, let alone a stylish custom-made suit.

---

On the wider issue of whether the plastic prison supplies clothes to people who inadvertently wear metal, my guess is that they follow [US prison visiting procedures](http://www.doc.state.nc.us/dop/visitation/) and bar entry to those who can't follow the rules:

> *"The dress code will be strictly enforced. **It will be the inmate’s
>   responsibility to communicate these standards to his/her visitors"***

Comment: or buttons? ....

Comment: @BenBolker - That would be too easy.

Answer (score 2):

Also worth considering is that Xavier is in a wheelchair and thus may very well use real-life adaptive clothing in general - regardless of who he is visiting on a particular day. Adaptive clothing may be easier to don and doff than standard clothes that folks without paraplegia and similar issues wear.

Not being able to stand or extend your legs make zippering very difficult - (psychokinetics notwithstanding)

Here is a website as an example:
http://www.silverts.com/show.php/product/50630-arthritis-mens-fleece-velcro-pants-with-velcro-strap-brand-closures

[image]